# How to use ELMO Embeddings as the First Embedding Layer in tf 2.0 Keras using tf-hub?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to build a `NER` model in `Keras` using `ELMO` Embeddings. SO I stumped across [this tutorial](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/named-entity-recognition-with-residual-lstm-and-elmo/) and started implementing. I got lots of errors and some of them are as:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from keras import backend as K


sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)

elmo_model = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())

def ElmoEmbedding(x):
    return elmo_model(inputs={"tokens": tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)),
                            "sequence_len": tf.constant(batch_size*[max_len])},signature="tokens",as_dict=True)["elmo"]

input_text = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.string)
embedding = Lambda(ElmoEmbedding, output_shape=(None, 1024))(input_text)
```

It gives me  `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'` . So if I comment out `sess=` code and run, it gives me `AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_session'`.

Then again, `Elmo` code line is giving me `RuntimeError: Exporting/importing meta graphs is not supported when eager execution is enabled. No graph exists when eager execution is enabled.`.

I have the following configurations:

```
tf.__version__
'2.3.1'

keras.__version__
'2.4.3'

import sys
sys.version
'3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 17:30:36) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

How can I use `ELMO` Embeddings in Keras Model?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the old Tensorflow 1.x syntax but you have tensorflow 2 installed.

This is the new way to do elmo in TF2
[Extracting ELMo features using tensorflow and convert them to numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67298869/extracting-elmo-features-using-tensorflow-and-convert-them-to-numpy)